# How to confirm requests are parallel / concurrent

Tags: javascript, concurrency, async-await

It would be pretty difficult to post sample code from the application but I'd just like to know if there's a way to ensure my `async` functions are called concurrently and not sequentially?

Should I just log start and end time or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe the network tab in you browser's developer tools.

If you open them before making the calls you can usually observe the waterfall of calls which is an easy way to determine if the are parallel or not.

Comment: It would appear so yes, otherwise the second line would start once the first one has ended.